# Kernel panic in OS X when calling proc_rele() inside a kext

Tags: c, macos, kernel, darwin, kernel-extension

I got a kernel panic, and can't figure out why.

What conditions could **possibly** cause the following function to crash in a kernel extension in OS X 10.11.3, resulting in a panic?

```
static int parent_pid(int pid) {
    int ppid = 0;
    proc_t process = proc_find(pid);
    if (process) {
        ppid = proc_ppid(process);
        proc_rele(process);
    }
    return ppid;
}
```

The panic occurred inside the `proc_rele()`, as it called `_lck_mtx_lock` in turn. To the best of my knowledge, the `proc_rele()` is used absolutely correctly here. There are no other calls to `proc_find()` or `proc_self()` in the entire kext, so the reason shouldn't be a missing `proc_rele()` somewhere else in the code.

Are there some kind of race conditions or thread issues I haven't considered? Do I need to protect calls to `proc_find()`/`proc_rele()` with a lock, for example?

Comment: Looks fine to me. I suspect your real bug is elsewhere - maybe an over-release somewhere else in your code, or a memory overwrite. The various public `proc_*` KPIs already do all the necessary locking for you. Add some more proc-related code from your kext to the question if you can't find the problem.